# Accessing Same Instance of already created view

Tags: java, android, eclipse, instance

I have an instance of an object created in my onCreate in my main android project. I have created a menu item which is outside of the menu item but I want to access the same instance. How do I do this? (I can't make the instance global since the onCreate would not have been called yet.

```
public class My_Main extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my__main);
    final new_viewer pv = new new_viewer(this);
}
}

public void test()
{
//how can I get the same instance of pv here?
}
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just declare it at class(Activity) level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `private new_viewer pv;` as **Class Level Variable** for `My_Main Activity`, like,

```
public class My_Main extends Activity {
 private new_viewer pv = null;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my__main);
    pv = new new_viewer(this);
 }


 public void test()
 {
 //Access pv here..
 }
}
```

Also Put your `test()` function inside of My_Main Activity scope..

Comment: This may need constructor as new_viewer is final ?

Comment: There are more problems to the original code than just this, `test()` is outside the `My_Main` class...

Comment: @AndroidKiller - No need of constructor, You have to just initialize it. like `new_viewer pv = null;`

Comment: @user370305, yeah, then it's ok. +1.

Comment: @user370305 thanks.. I didnt know that pv would still hold the value of this. Anyways i ended up makeing a singleton (But i'll most likely switch it to this as it is less confusing) Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be a disease spreading through SO. A *global variable" has application wide scope.  This is a class level variable.